# final optional member variable in Java classes

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, pmd

I have a scenario where some of the final variables declared at class level are optional in some cases.

That means I have different constructors. Some of those have to leave the member variables with null values.

Since I have declared the variable as final, I am forced to initialize those in the constructor. So I have to add *var = null;* statement in the constructor.

But explicitly assigning variables to null is considered to be a bad practice and tools like PMD, reports it as a violation. (Controversial rule in PMD. But do not want to switch it off, since I do not want the null assignment to be practiced in other areas of my code)

Any other suggessions or good practices to achieve this?

Comment: Hm....smells like an Inheritance problem. :)

Comment: a simple code sample demonstrating your problem will be more useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use constructor chaining, passing null to the values that are not used in your instance. (You can either use the super constructor if we are discussing inheritance, or a different constructor in the same class.)
After all I would reconsider the design of your classes, for example extract the optional part to a different class.

Answer (score 0):

**Instance variables are assigned default values(null in case of custom object).**

So unless you are really assigning some value to your final variables why bother about null assignments?

As user has pointed out in the comment above does not stand good for final variables. So what can be done define a no-arg constructor with all final values set to null.

Now in individual arg constructors place a call to this default constructor by using `this()` as the 1st statement .. then you can assign values depending on the arguments passed.

Comment: Not when the variable is marked as final. We will have to explicitly have assignment statements in constructor for final variables. Else compiler will complain.

Answer (score 0):

**What you are looking for is the builder pattern.**

Say you have a class with a constructor that accepts all the values:

```
class Job {
    private final Integer id;
    private final String name;
    private final Boolean retry;

    public class Job(Integer id, String name, Boolean retry) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.retry = retry;
    }
}
```

Now, you want to let other create different flavors of that object while keeping it immutable, removing the default value logic from it and keeping it clean. **You create a new builder class:**

```
class JobBuilder {
    // Values the user MUST provide are non-initialized and
    // declared as final
    private final Integer id; 

    // Values the user MAY provide are initialized with default values
    // and are not final
    private String name = "[none]";
    private Boolean retry = true;

    public class JobBuilder(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public JobBuilder name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public JobBuilder retry(Boolean retry) {
        this.retry = retry; 
    }

    public Job build() {
        return new Job(this.id, this.name, this.retry);
    }
}
```

Now, you can create different job objects easily while enforcing the requirements:

```
Job job1 = JobBuilder(1).name("firstJob").retry(false).build();

Job job2 = JobBuilder(2).name("secondJob").build();

Job job3 = JobBuilder(3).build();
```